# php - percentage chance of winning

Tags: php

Currently I have this:

```
$chance = 5;
    #Set the winning chances.
    function winningChance($percentage)
    {
        if ($percentage < 0 || $percentage > 100)
            throw new Exception('Invalid percentage');

        return rand(0, 100) <= $percentage ? 'won' : 'lost';
    }

    if(winningChance($chance) == "lost"){
        $won = false; //You lost.   
    }else{
        $won = true; //You won.
    }
```

This is really simple. It seems like even though the $chance is set to 5, the winning occur way more often than it should. 
Can anyone suggest me how to improve this?

Comment: I wonder if there is an alphabetical rather than numerical comparison going on. In which case you might have a 50-50 split (roughly). Can you try `rand(0,100) - $percentage <= 0` and see if that works better? It forces things to be treated as numbers, not strings.

Comment: Are you sure that you are winning more often?  Check your results with 1000+ executions and see if you are winning at about the percentage that you think.

Comment: @Schleis - with a desired percentage of 5%, I think you would see it pretty quickly... but quantifying with a large number of samples is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Given @ComFreek's finding  - are you sure your code is _exactly_ as you give it? What is the source of your "winning percentage". Is it a text box?

Comment: **Your script works fine for me**! See here: https://eval.in/56777 (@Floris: my sample was incorrect because I misspelt one variable and that caused the total sample to be wrong.)

Comment: It should be working as you desire. I got a 6% on 5% chance -- [CodePad](http://codepad.org/ihs1jFpo)

Comment: @Floris I think he refers to my eval.in link in a previous comment which I have deleted now.

Comment: @oliverbj - in your comment to the now-deleted answer you asked me to create a sample program. The comments by UnholyRanger and ComFreek already have examples with a loop to count multiple occurrences. Perhaps your problem was indeed with seeding? If so, then people did an injustice by downvoting the solution...

Comment: @Floris Seeding is never a problem when it comes to measuring the probabilities. It only affects the (pre-computed) order of pseudo-random numbers. It is generally hard to recognize the probability without generating thousands of (pseudo-)random numbers. That is OP's problem, I think.

Comment: @ComFreek - my point was that if OP ran the code once, then again once, etc, he might see 100% success. In that situation, seeding would actually help. It seems we are having a bit of a conversation among ourselves though - I would like to hear from olivierbj himself to see whether all this conversation has cleared things up.

Comment: @Floris PHP's random number generators have been seeded automatically since PHP 4.2.0, so the results should be different every time the program is run, and even manually invoking it repeatedly should *tend towards* the right proportion of "wins".

Comment: @IMSoP I am glad to hear it - I did not know that. 4.2.0 was released in April 2002. You'd have thought I had read the memo by now...